# Kotlin flatMap - map

Tags: kotlin

Say I have a list of size 30k elements, and I would like to perform an operation on all possible pairs within a list. So I had:

```
 list.asSequence().flatMap { i -> 
         list.asSequence().map { j -> /* perform operation here */ }
 }
```

**Question 1:**
Is there anything that I can use as an alternative? (Such as applicative functors).

I also noticed that this flatMap-map operation is significantly slower than the imperative loop version. (perhaps due to closures?)

```
for(i in list){
    for(j in list){

    }
}
```

**Question 2:** Is there a way to improve the performance of the flatMap/map version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to the question 2, we're considering to add `flatMap` overload which doesn't create closures for each element in the outer collection/sequence: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8602

But in case if you want to perform some side effects on each pair, rather than transforming the sequence, I'd advice to stick with `for`-loops or inlined `forEach` lambdas, which is effectively the same.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) I would be glad if this KT-8602 will be considered, or something like a nested list comprehension, really lookin forward to it

Answer (score 3):

Some alternatives with performance impacts:

1. [com.google.common.collect.Sets.cartesianProduct(java.util.Set...)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#cartesianProduct(java.util.Set...)): "Returns every possible list that can be formed by choosing one element from each of the given sets in order; the 'n-ary [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)' of the sets."

   - This requires your list elements to be unique. If they're not then you'd have to wrap each element in a unique object so that they can all be added to the input set.
   - In my testing, however, I've found it to be slower than the `flatMap`/`map` solution. :-(
2. `forEach`/`forEach`: As you simply want to perform an operation on each pair then you don't actually need to use `flatMap` or `map` to transform the list so you can use `forEach`/`forEach` instead:

   ```
   list.forEach { i ->
       list.forEach { j -> /* perform operation here */ }
   }
   ```

   - In my testing I've found this to be slightly faster than the `for`/`for` solution. :-)

If you do need to transform the list then your `flatMap`/`map` solutions appears to be the best solution.

Comment: Guava is Kotlin-compatible?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Guava can be used in Kotlin when targeting the JVM, yes.